# zc.buildout is using the wrong python

Tags: python, egg

I'm using zc.buildout to generate a script called "test".  I'm using that script to call my own test runner.  (The available test runners for buildout do not yet use the new "discovery" feature in Python 2.7.)

Anyhow, here's the relevant section in my .cfg file:

```
[test]
recipe = buildout_script
template = runtests.sh.in
target = test
```

Here is what my runtests.sh.in template looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

python %(directory)s/src/runtests.py
```

And here is the resulting output that is placed in my bin folder as `bin/test`.

```
!/bin/bash

python /Users/myname/projects/myproject/trunk/www/src/desktop/src/runtests.py
```

When I execute this script, it's using the system Python instead of the Python in my bin folder.

The relevant section for that in my .cfg file is:

```
[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
```

**How do I get my script to use bin/python instead of the system python?**

Answer (score 0):

In your bash script, your are relying upon `$PATH` to determine which python to use.  To change which python is invoked, you have several choices:

1. Modify your environment to prefer a different version, i.e. in ~/.bashrc, add `export PATH=/path/to/desired/python/bin:$PATH` (of course with the appropriate substitutions
2. Modify your bash script to explicitly state the path to python, thus avoiding using `$PATH` at all.
3. Remove the explicit invocation of python, and change the sha-bang in the python script to select the appropriate version. (also, make sure the python script is marked executable).

Comment: I don't want to directly use any other version of Python installed in my system.  The buildout has created the script called myproject/bin/python.  The first thing this script does is add stuff to the path.  I want to keep using that facility.

Answer (score 0):

You need to substitute the value of `${buildout:executable}` into the template. I'm not sure how you refer to that using the buildout_script recipe, perhaps `%(executable)s`?

Comment: That outputted /usr/bin/python :( :( :( :(